# How to test a controller with steps to use some action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, controller

In my system, I have a user that have one company that have multiple accounts.
User sign in system using Devise, and have a virtual attribute called selected_company that was setted in CompaniesController.
I want to make multiple tests in AccountsController with this scenario.
I have this code to sign_in user, this code works well:

```
before :each do
  @user = create(:user)
  @user.confirm!
  sign_in @user
end
```

But I must to have a specific context that I tried to code as:

```
context 'when user already selected a company' do
  before :each do
    @company = create(:company)
    @account = create(:account)
    @company.accounts << @account
    @user.selected_company = @company
  end

  it "GET #index must assings @accounts with selected_company.accounts" do
    get :index
    expect(assigns(accounts)).to match_array [@account]
  end
end
```

But this code won't work, when I run it I got this error:

```
undefined method `accounts' for nil:NilClass
```

My AccountsController#index have only this code:

```
def index
  @accounts = current_user.selected_company.accounts
end
```

I'm new in rspec and TDD and I have some time to test everything I want, and I want to test everything to practice rspec.
I don't know if this is the best way to test this things, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I found the problem!
I changed the `before` statement to:

```
before :each do
  @company = create(:company)
  @account = create(:account)
  @company.accounts << @account
  controller.current_user.selected_company = @company
end
```

And changed `assigns(accounts)` to `assings(:accounts)` (with symbol) in expect method.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with:

```
expect(assigns(:accounts)).to match_array [@accounts]
```

Note, `:accounts` instead of just `account`.
Also, as I see it, you don't have `@accounts` in your spec. Please declare that, too. :)

Comment: Sorry, I typed `@accounts` instead `@account`. In my code I used @account, that was declared in before(:each) statment.

Comment: Yes, I inferred that. But had to notify you, in case you really meant `@accounts`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not saving selected_company and when you call this on your controller it returns nil.

Try save `@user.save` after set selected_company:

```
context 'when user already selected a company' do
  before :each do
    @company = create(:company)
    @account = create(:account)
    @company.accounts << @account
    @user.selected_company = @company
    @user.save
  end

  it "GET #index must assings @accounts with selected_company.accounts" do
    get :index
    expect(assigns(accounts)).to match_array [@account]
  end
end
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: Hi man, I already tried to save `@user`, but not works too... anyway, thanks for try to help me :)

Comment: Hey Bruno I've realised about one there are only two places where it could this exception.

First: Where I already mention.
Second: On this `@company.accounts << @account` of code.

On the second, try to create the company factory using create!(:company) it's probably when called.

Comment: `undefined method create! for #<RSpec::Core::ExempleGroup...>` I tried with FactoryGirl.create! and have same error :(